# jQuery sortable and AJAX question. (sortable not working when the list comes from AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 sortable lists. The first one is getting the elements with AJAX from database (like pagination, I do not want 200 item at once on that list). The second one is empty at first and I want to fill it with elements from the first.

I'm very new to jQuery and AJAX so I want to apologize in advance for any stupid thing that I will say.

Sortable is not working on the first list when I get elements with AJAX.

This is what I use for sortable:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
            cursor:'crosshair',
            connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
        }).disableSelection()
        });
```

This is the AJAX part:

```
jQuery('.nav').click(function(event) { 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",url: "admin-ajax.php",
            data: { action: 'ak_attach', 'lim': jQuery(event.target).attr("name"),_ajax_nonce: '' },
            beforeSend: function() {jQuery("#loading").fadeIn('fast');},
            success: function(msg){
            jQuery(".listContent").html(msg)

            }
        }); //close jQuery.ajax
        return false;
    })
})
```

regards,
bo

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable( 'refresh' )` after you add the new values to the list? This will cause jquery to see the new values and resort if needed.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: The only place I could think off calling it is after AJAX complete or success. Still nothing.

Comment: You need to call it inside of the success function, you tried that already?